# Grabbing value from Jquery Datepicker

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, angularjs, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using a Jquery datepicker, and am getting some confusing behavior. I am using angular JS as a javascript framework, and it looks something like this.

```
<p>
    <input type= "text" id="datetime1" ng-model= "dt1" ng-change= "reset_results()">
    </input>
</p>
```

In my javascript file, I am able to access the value of the datepicker by doing something like...

```
var date_val = $scope.dt1;
```

However (and I know this is usually the opposite of the way things work in web dev) This works in IE ONLY. When I try to run this on Firefox, I get a value of undefined for the datepicker value. That is, in IE, date_val equals what I want. In Firefox, date_val is undefined.

I know one work around is doing something like...

```
var date_val = $("#datetime1").datepicker('getDate');
```

However, this produces a format that would require me to change code elsewhere. For example, I have a function that is used to validate the input from the user. This is done by passing the Angular JS $scope variable to a helper function. I cannot simply do something like...

```
$scope.dt1 = $("#datetime1").datepicker('getDate');
```

Because then this wonky format is displayed as part of the view on my page, inside the text field. Does anyone know of a way to make the ng-model part of the code work for firefox?

Comment: I hacked at it and got it to work, I just set the $scope variable before I make the validation check, but I would still like to know why my scope variable is automatically picking up the value of the datepicker in IE, but not FF.

Comment: changed the formatting on the date before sending it to validation check.